# TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I am facing an issue which was not occurring before, maybe some rules have been changed.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-3-f47687e192a7> in <module>()
          5 n_examples = X.shape[0]
          6 n_train = n_examples * 0.5
    ----> 7 train_idx = np.random.choice(range(0,n_examples), size=n_train, replace=False)
          8 test_idx = list(set(range(0,n_examples))-set(train_idx))
          9 X_train = X[train_idx]

    mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.choice (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:18822)()

    TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

Comment: Just a guesse, but `n_train = n_examples * 0.5` may not be an int. Try to do: `n_train = int(n_examples * 0.5)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue might be with  the `range` function, which comes with Python. Its arguments must be integers. `n_train` gets turned to a float when `n_examples` is multiplied by `0.5`. You just need to reconvert it to an int like `int(n_examples * 0.5)`. This is actually the correct thing to do. If you'd have `11` examples, it wouldn't make sense to have `5.5` training and test examples.

Comment: if this was the correct answer, please flag it as such so that Horia may reap his sweet reputation points.