# TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index, how to solve it?

Tags: python

The error message is:

```
File "dry.py", line 1184, in < module >
grid = getmap(grid)
File "dry.py", line 690, in getmap
data = array(data, 'f').reshape(pts[2], pts[1], pts[0])
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Convert your floats to ints...

Comment: You ca cast to int. int(pts[0]) etc

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086584/typeerror-float-object-cannot-be-interpreted-as-an-index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you write in your question an example of what the values of  pts[0], pts[1], pts[2] looks like?

if the values are close to integers (like 1.00004 or 3.9998) you can use the round function to round the values to the nearest integer like:

```
data = array(data, 'f').reshape(round(pts[2]), round(pts[1]), round(pts[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of `pts[i]` (for `i` in `[0,1,2]`)

Are these `int`s or `float`s? `int`s are needed for this API.

If you find floats that are very close to an integer like `3.0` or `2.99` then clearly `int`s were intended.

Simply use `int(pts[i])` instead of `pts[i]` (and/or check how these indexes were converted to `float`).

If you find values that were not meant to be `int`, like `2.4`, then you will need to debug that.

Answer (score 0):

The function [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) takes `int` or tuple of ints. You are trying to pass `float`. But you can't.

By the way you can cast your float object to int like `int(pts[0])`